# getting back to main thread from NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nstimer

I have a `NSTimer` defined like:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.speed target:self selector:@selector(displayTextOverTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The method `displayTextOverTime` displays some text, then once the last piece of text is displayed it invalidates it's timer and calls another method for processing (which itself may need to start a `NSTimer` to display text).

Is there a standard way to do this sort of thing?

My original approach was to simply have `displayTextOverTime` call the other method directly, but that's getting me some weird behavior where I have nested `NSTimer`s (which never die, because even though they are invalidated and won't loop again, they aren't 'done' because the timer inside of them is still running...or...something?), which is NOT what I want.  Is there some way to say "call this method, but do it outside of this `NSTimer`", like back on the main thread?

Specifically, I am seeing more timers being killed than started (I have a method for killing any passed in timer so I can log when it's being killed).

Comment: There is the `NSObject` method [`performObjectOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-CJBEHAEF).

Comment: 1. There is no point to creating a repeatable timer and then invalidate it on every invocation. 2. You can call performSelector:afterDelay with a delay of zero - that method will run on the next loop of the main runloop.

Comment: To EricS, I'm not invalidating it on every invocation. Rather, I'm saying: "Call this method every X ms until it lets you know it's done, then call THIS method every X ms until it lets you know it's done". This displays text one word every time at an easy reading speed, then goes to fetch more text (if it exists), then displays it one word at a time again.

Comment: performObjectOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:  works like a charm. Thanks user1118321!  I'll accept the only answer I have, though....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an exact answer to your question, you could use Grand Central Dispatch to run a function outside of your timer.  Were you want to run the function put this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        (your function or block of code goes here)
    });
```

That will run the block outside of your timer.  You can chose to do this on the main thread, global thread, or custom thread with a queue that you create.